# builder.EntitySet meaning

Tags: .net, odata

I tried to google it, but in all examples it is not well explained. What exactly does the method EntitySet() in the following context?

```
    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.ContainerName = "DefaultContainer";

        builder.EntitySet<HouseEntity>("Houses");

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

I understand that it allows HouseEntity objects to be consumed from this service. But what does the Parameter "Houses" stand for. I first thought, that it is the name of the controller, but this seems to be not true. 
The name of the route? Name of a class? What does the string param stand for?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EntitySet method will build the model based on kinds of conversion, and for your example,

1. It will add an Entity Type named HouseEntity into model.
2. It will add an Entity Set with Name Houses and its type is HouseEntity into container.

In order to request Houses like get, you will need to create a Controller named HousesController which extends ODataController to route the request.

You can refer to http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#02-04-convention-model-builder for detail information about the model builder.

And refer to http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-01-routing-abstract about the detail of routing.

If document is still unclear, you can open issue on https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues.

Comment: Thanks, that for the moment answers my question.